# JSON received different from JSON sent with Spring Rest and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-rest

I'm having difficulties with Spring Rest & Hibernate. I'm doing API calls from my Android application and one of the POST Calls seems to have an issue.

I have 2 classes : `Player` and `Game`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Game", schema = "statistics")
public class GameEntity {
    private int matchId;
    private int firstPlayer;
    private int secondPlayer;

    @Column(name = "first_player")
    public int getFirstPlayer() {
        return firstPlayer;
    }

    public void setFirstPlayer(int firstPlayer) {
        this.firstPlayer = firstPlayer;
    }

    @Column(name = "second_player")
    public int getSecondPlayer() {
        return secondPlayer;
    }

    public void setSecondPlayer(int secondPlayer) {
        this.secondPlayer = secondPlayer;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Players", schema = "statistics")
public class PlayersEntity {
    private int playerId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int id) {
        this.playerId = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }Ga

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I send a POST for `Player` : it works. 
However when I do the same for `Game` it refuses it because it doesn't receive the values correctly - when I debugged the `@RequestBody` I found that the Entity received contained incorrect values (all were 0's since all the fields are Integers) :

[image: incorrect json values]

Even though, the JSON sent had the correct values :

[image: correct JSON]

And I end up with a SQL Error (because 2 of the 3 id's in `Game` are foreign keys referencing `Player`).

I really don't see why and I don't know how to log HTTP Requests/Responses on Spring.

Anyways, thanks in advance to anybody who would guide me to a right response & stay safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is:

In your entities the field is called "firstPlayer", whereas in your JSON the field is called "first_player".

Note, the @Column annotation you put on the field is only valid for storing into a database table, not for JSON conversions between your backend and frontend.

For that, I would probably build a custom DTO/VO instead of reusing your @Entity, with the appropriate Jackson mapping annotations: @JsonProperty.

```
@JsonProperty("player_id")
private int playerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSON Deserialization doesn't look at JPA annotations.
Therefore there is a mismatch between JSON you send, which uses `snake_case` and Java properties, which are in `camelCase`

There are at least 3 options to solve this issue:

**Enable Snake-case application-wide**

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

**Enable Snake-Case for specific class**

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class GameEntity {

}
```

**Provide a custom JsonCreator constructor**

Note that default constructor is also necessary for JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Game", schema = "statistics")
public class GameEntity {
    private int matchId;
    private int firstPlayer;
    private int secondPlayer;

    public GameEntity() {}

    @JsonCreator
    public GameEntity(@JsonProperty("match_id") int matchId,
                      @JsonProperty("first_player") int firstPlayer,
                      @JsonProperty("second_player") int secondPlayer) {
        this.matchId = matchId;
        this.firstPlayer = firstPlayer;
        this.secondPlayer = secondPlayer;
    }

    ...

}
```

Note that there is an extra mismatch: you have `matchId` in Java and `game_id` in JSON. Only the third approach lets you solve it without renaming the field in Java